# How did the Holy Spirit come into existence?

Tags: creation, trinity, pneumatology

Who created the Holy Spirit? Did the Holy Spirit exist from the beginning or was it God who created the Holy Spirit? If it was God, then why is it said that the members of the Holy Trinity is independent of each other but form an eternal  Triune God?

Comment: This question will need to be limited to a particular tradition as there are differences in opinion.  Some traditions reject the trinity.

Comment: I think it is fair to ascribe this to a Trinitarian perspective, and in leiu of a named tradition, declare the classic formulation of Nicene Christianity.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to mainstream Christianity, the Holy Spirit is a person of the Trinity - loosely speaking a part of God. Therefore he was not created. He is eternal, without beginning and without end. This is best (though not necessarily most understandably) summed up in the [Athenasian Creed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athanasian_Creed):

> Such as the Father is; such is the Son; and such is the Holy Ghost. The Father uncreated; the Son uncreated; and the Holy Ghost uncreated.

Something around 98% of Christians adhere to this view.

For those that do not believe in the Trinity, the Holy Spirit is usually considered to be an 'impersonal force', or the action of God, or simply another way of referring to God (as opposed to a separate person). In these cases there is also no question of "who created the Holy Spirit". He has always existed.

Comment: This answer would be improved by a reference to the Nicene Creed, in which we read that that the Holy Spirit proceeds through the Father and/or through the Son ([filioque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filioque)!), as well as the notion of the heresy that says the Father is superior to the Son and the Spirit, because of the order of creation.  It's a good start though!

Comment: I don't think the filioque disagreements don't really impact the question as asked. Both sides would agree that the Holy Spirit is uncreated.

Comment: When you mention the 'impersonal force' doctrine, that is typically a Jehova's Whitness doctrine. The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter Day Saints (Mormons) Believe that The Father, the Son, and the Holy Ghost are distinct beings that are one in purpose.

Answer (score 0):

According to the theory of the trinity, the holy spirit was never created as the theory holds that the holy spirit is god just as the father is god and the son is god. Since the trinity theory promotes that the father and the son are from eternity, so then is the holy spirit also uncreated.

According to scripture, the Holy Spirit is uncreated as the Holy Spirit is the operational presence and power of Yahuweh (God), but is not a seperate person from Yahuweh (God) Himself. Though not being a seperate person, the Holy Spirit is still "personal" just not a "person".

> 2 Corinthians 3:17 The Scriptures 1998+  (17)  Now יהוה is the Spirit, and where the Spirit of יהוה is, there is freedom.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Here we don't try to decide between conflicting claims to 'truth' among Christian groups. We report on what Christians believe to be true. Your view about what scripture says, while valid for you, is not agreed with by the majority of Christians.

Comment: It'll be helpful to explain "personal" and yet not a "person." That's bewildering. The Holy Spirit is separate from Jesus, taking and receiving from Him (John 16_13-15) and is called "He" and not it. This and more attributes constitute a person in my book.

Comment: "Not a separate person" is not doctrinally representative of Nicene Christianity (i.e. the vast majority).

Comment: @Steve - The original question did not require such. However, you should look into the greek and the context surrounding those scriptures to determine "he", "she", "it". Also look into the gender designation of the Holy Spirit as it's used in the Hebrew texts. Don't rely solely on the English translations.

Comment: @Caleb - Nicene Christianity isn't representative of scriptural Christianity or the beliefs and life of our Messiah. Catholic councils don't have the right to change scripture and dictate what's true. Also, do some research into history. The Nicene council isn't representative of the council of Calcedon nor is it representative of the council of Constantinople. The Holy Spirit wasn't even included in the original Nicene creed.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what this site is about. We're not here to argue truth -- the way you think it should be -- or even the real way it should be -- is irrelevant. We're here to talk about what Christianity thinks. And your answer here is patently out of step with that (and does not identify the viewpoint it's speaking from). And I'm aware of the historical issues with those councils ...

Comment: _<This discussion was [moved to and continued in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9099/discussion-between-wax-eagle-and-the-duke-of-marshall)>_

Answer (score -1):

In most languages other than English the word for Spirit and the word for breath are the same word.  The creation story tells us the earth was without form and the "spirit," or "breath" of God hovered above the waters or abyss.  According to the Gospel of John, Jesus was the "word of God that was with God and was God."  When God spoke creation into being the word spoken was Jesus and the Holy Spirit is the breath that makes the word active creating cosmos from chaos.
The Holy Spirit is present and observable because it is the fundamental aspect of God (the Trinity) that transforms matter (God's creation) to be what God intends it to be.  The Spirit, breath or wind of God is actually God breathing life into his creation.

Comment: While what you've written is true, you haven't actually explained how the Holy Spirit came into existence.

Comment: @curiousdannii is correct, as worded this does not answer the question, although it DOES come close.   This can be fixed by simply adding "The Holy Spirit was present at the beginning because..."  Please consider editing this to address the actual question explicitly instead of leaving it for the audience to connect the dots.